# What does $p^2_\theta$ mean in the context of a photon described by its four momentum?

Tags: black-holes, coordinate-systems, geodesics

The paper [Null Geodesics of the Kerr Exterior](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12881.pdf) shows the equation

$$Q = p_ \theta^2 - \cos^2\theta(a^2 p_t^2 - p_\phi^2 \csc^2\theta),$$

where $p$, the four-momentum of a photon, has superscript 2 and subscript $\theta$. I understand the 2 symbolizes the third part of the momentum, but what does the $\theta$ part mean? If it is the $\theta$ of the Boyer-Lindquist coordinate, does $p_\theta^2$ mean $p^2\times(\theta \text{ of the position of the photon})$?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to put the equation here, so it is linked as an image in Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit boring: it's just a square. It's the covariant component $p_\theta$, squared. I guess they thought their readers would be familiar enough with the subject to understand it, but there's really no other option anyway. Since $\theta$ can only be a subscript, 2 can only be a square.

Comment: That's on my part: I thought it was the square, but I wasn't really sure since it seems like both. It didn't make sense to convert anything to coordinates here, thanks